# Is there a way to (automatically) detect if the channels of a stereo video/audio are out of phase and canceling each other?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing

#### Background

I've encountered an issue while attempting to convert an audio downloaded from a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3QB_rJzH08) into a mono .wav format using `ffmpeg`. Despite using typical conversion commands (code below), the resulting audio is either silent or corrupted, indicating potential stereo channel cancellation.
I tried to load the audio into Python and calculate phase and cross-correlation, but this step uses a lot of memory, especially for a 6-hour-long audio.

#### Goal

I'm seeking a method, preferably using `ffmpeg`, to detect if stereo channels are canceling each other out due to phase misalignment. Additionally, I aim to automate the process of phase inversion before converting to mono to ensure the integrity of the resulting audio.

#### Question:

How can I automatically detect if stereo channels are canceling each other and subsequently invert the phase to ensure successful conversion to mono using `ffmpeg`? Any insights, solutions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

#### Steps Taken:

1. Downloaded audio from YouTube using `yt-dlp`.
2. Attempted audio conversion to mono using `ffmpeg`, resulting in silent or corrupted output.
3. Successfully converted audio to mono by manually inverting the phase of one channel prior to conversion.

#### Download audio from youtube

```
yt-dlp -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3QB_rJzH08 -o input.webm
```

#### Audio conversion

The resulting file is silent or corrupted

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm  -ac 1 -ar 16000 -c:a pcm_s16le output.wav
```

#### Audio conversion to mono .wav with phase inversion

The resulting file has audio

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -af "aeval=val(0)|-val(1)" -ac 1 -ar 16000 -c:a pcm_s16le output.wav
```

Comment: it's not phase/phase shift (phenomenon in time), it's inversion (phenomenon in amplitude/space). there is a difference in meaning even though most people don't care.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz cool, thanks! Any advice on how to detect inversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg has a phase difference detection filter.

`ffmpeg -i input.webm -af "aphasemeter=video=0:phasing=1:angle=90:duration=1:tolerance=0.001,ametadata=print:file=aphase.log" -vn -f null -`

The file `aphase.log` will contain a per-frame log of phase difference in the format

```
frame:17302 pts:19931904 pts_time:451.971
lavfi.aphasemeter.phase=0.224391
```

The phase value can range from -1 to +1. `-1` indicates the channels are completely out of phase and `1` means channels are in phase.

If the channels are out of phase, ffmpeg will also print a summary reading in the console log.

Comment: Thank you very much @gyan! I'll check the meaning of the parameters at the documentation.
Do you know if I can calculate the phase, let's say, every 300 seconds?